# How to use google cloud path(gs://) to get all train files and test files in google cloud bucket to train the jobs in ai-platform

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm working on the packaging of a training application on the Google cloud platform. I test the code locally using `python -m` and `gcloud ai-platform local train` it working find. But when I submit my job to google cloud, the path to training and testing dataset(which is in google bucket) doesn't work.

My bucket directory:

```
my-models
  |
  |--dataset
      |-train_set
      |    |-cat(100 files inside)
      |    |-dog(100 files inside)
      |
      |-test_set
           |-cat(30 files inside)
           |-dog(30 files inside)
```

I using this command to submit my jobs

```
$JOB_ID --job-dir=$BUCKET_PATH_FOR_JOB \
        --staging-bucket=$BUCKET_NAME \
        --package-path=trainer \
        --module-name=trainer.task \
        --python-version=3.5 \
        --region=us-east1 \
        --runtime-version=1.14 \
        -- \
        --train_path='gs://my-models/dataset/train_set/' \
        --test_path='gs://my-models/dataset/test_set/' \
...
```

Here are some of my code:

```py
def get_args():
    parser.add_argument(
        '--train_path',
        type=Path,
        action='store',
        help='GCS or local path to training data',
        required=True
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--test_path',
        type=Path,
        action='store',
        help='GCS or local path to testing data',
        required=True
    )
    return parser.parse_args()

def get_classes(train_path, test_path):
    train_dataset = list()
    test_dataset = list()
    train_classes = os.listdir(train_path)
    test_classes = os.listdir(test_path)

    return train_classes, test_classes

def main():
    args = get_args()
    train_path = args.train_path
    test_path = args.test_path
    train_classes, test_classes = get_classes(train_path, test_path)
...
```

I expect the output of the list of directory `cat` and `dog` from train_path and test_path. Also, the possible way to read files in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling too less about your model. But, if you use an [`imageGenerator` you don't have to label your image because they are in the right directory](https://youtu.be/u2TjZzNuly8?t=102)

Add more info about your code for understanding what it is doing with the list of file that you provide to it!